# I still write web apps in ASP Legacy -- What is a good modern alternative to this platform?

Tags: asp-classic

Hi and thanks for reading,

I still write web applications in classic ASP, and I would like to move to a more modern web application platform. What languages and frameworks offer a reasonable migration path from classic ASP in the year 2011?

Thanks for your help,
Will

Comment: There is no such thing as an ideal language for all purposes. Voting to close as subjective.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  What are the newer language options for building web forms and their advantages or disadvantages.  I feel I need to move off of ASP Classic in the coming months.

Comment: Will - edited your comment to take out "web forms" (which is confusing due to close association with ASP.NET WebForms) and replaced "language" with "framework" - because classic ASP supports multiple scripting languages, it sounded like you were asking about VBScript vs JSCript vs PerlScript for writing new classic ASP apps, not about modern frameworks and alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Dylan -- my jargon just ain't what it used to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ASP.NET MVC.** I wrote classic ASP for 10+ years, including full implementations of ActiveRecord-style business objects and domain entities. I started out in VBScript but switched to JScript around 2003 and never looked back. I worked on every release of ASP.NET from the pre-1.0 beta, and absolutely hated the code-behind event-driven model - ViewState, OnClick handlers, just felt like completely the wrong way to work with a stateless protocol like HTTP and a markup language like HTML.

ASP.NET MVC was an absolute revelation; the first framework that felt like I was actually *using* the knowledge of requests, responses, headers and markup that I'd gained writing classic ASP. I'm now developing a handful of ASP.NET MVC apps as well as maintaining our legacy JScript/ASP codebase, and I genuinely think it's the cleanest migration path from legacy ASP to something modern, testable, object-oriented and elegant. The request, response, server, etc. objects are still there, and do (roughly!) the same things they did in classic ASP, but once you start to learn about ViewModels and controller attributes you'll quickly start writing much, much cleaner, more elegant code.

Comment: Can you write this in Eclipse?  I don't want to buy VS since it costs an arm and a leg.

Comment: You can write it in any text editor (in theory!) - in practise, you're better off with the free Visual Studio Express edition, which will do 90% of what you need whilst you're getting started.

Answer (score 0):

If you write web forms in ASP legacy (you mean Classic ASP?), then IMHO the simplest and logical transition is to ASP.NET.

If you choose ASP.NET, do yourself a favor and learn yourself ASP.NET (code-behind, data binding, etc.) so that you understand its basics. Some web developers who took the step from ASP to ASP.NET still write their websites "the legacy way" and miss many .NET advantages.

Comment: Is ASP.NET the best choice for building web forms compared to all other options?

Comment: Not necessarily, there are many options. But since you're familiar with ASP, I think the transition to ASP.NET is the easiest, compared to PHP (w/custom frameworks), Ruby o-R, Python, etc.

Comment: I am not necessarily concerned with the transition time...I just want to be able to build the cleanest-code web forms (without buying an IDE) in the fastest, most efficient way (after I get past the initial learning curve).

Comment: There's still a lot of choices, and I bet there'll be as many opinions as there are developers out there. Just as them, I'm not independent and would choose ASP.NET. But you should probably get around and try some solutions and conclude yourself which one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Imo, the smoothest transition from classic asp, is to php or python, not ASP.Net.

Classic ASP is a non compiled interpreted platform, so is php and python.  ASP.Net is compiled, and generally means needing full blown Visual Studio.

If you want to be able to build web apps in sublime, atom, visual studio code, or {Insert your favorite editor here} then php or python would be the way to go.  Python more so than php, it's much more modern, and has way more features.

And if you want to get really snazzy, you can ditch IIS entirely, and go with node.js and nginx.

Use node.js + gulp + express + angular + {insert database node module here}.

Use gulp to structure your Css and Javascript and set build tasks for your css and javascript, and by build I mean just minifying and trasnforming SASS (Scss) into .css, and concatenanting and minifying Javascript.

Use Nginx to serve the static compiled css and js files built by gulp.

Use Express to build fluent rest based web services in javascript in ES6.

Build your whole web app with angular and make it client heavy where all your server logic is rest based web services.

You can also ditch angular and lean more heavily on express.  There is an html template engine for express you can install in node and use express as an MVC framework.

Being entirely node and nginx... One well performing website, very fast, and easy to scale.

There is little need for a website to be on a compiled platform imo.  If you do end up with the need for compiler based performance, just build that part in compiled code.

E.g. you can have a website that's 90% python, or whatever, and the 10% that needs to be compiled do it in .Net Web Api 2, or Java on Spring.